# Setting up Koa 2 with Node 6.3

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, koa

I am trying to set up a project with Koa 2 and Node 6.3 and I would like to fill in the missing ES6/ES7 features in Node with Babel. This is my set up right now:

I have installed the following `npm` packages:

```
"babel-preset-node6": "^11.0.0",
"babel-register": "^6.9.0",
"koa": "^2.0.0",
```

My `.babelrc` is:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "node6"
  ]
}
```

My `index.js` is:

```
require('babel-register');
require('./app');
```

And my `app.js` is:

```
import Koa from 'koa';
const app = new Koa();

app.use(async (ctx) => {
  ctx.body = 'Hello world';
});

app.listen(3000);
```

When I run `node index.js` I get the error:

```
Unexpected token (4:20)
  2 | const app = new Koa();
  3 | 
> 4 | app.use(async (ctx) => {
    |                     ^
  5 |     ctx.body = 'Hello world';
  6 | });
```

Since Node 6.3 already supports natively 93% of all ES6 features, my goal is to have the minimum required Babel packages to fill in the missing features of ES6 and ES7. I guess I am missing a plugin to fill in the support for async, but I am not sure which one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to install the `transform-async-to-generator` plugin, as it is explained [here](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/v2.x/docs/api/index.md#async-functions-with-babel).

Comment: You could also install `babel-preset-stage-3` which installs that automatically (and more, think of it like a package), more info here https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-3/